# Why is VS Code showing errors when code works?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, sqlalchemy

i`m working with SQLAlchemy in VS Code. The code works fine when i run it but VS Code always shows an error (see Picture).

[image]

[image]

Why is VS Code showing a problem?
What am i doing wrong?
How to fix it?

Comment: I have a similar issue writing C++. In my case it usually happens at import lines but it usually is fixed after a while. Judging from my case it has to do with the path of the libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might actually be "false positive" error. Pylint checks your code for possible problems (and if it follows the [PEP8 style recommendation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

It seems (e.g., see [here](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/3765) or [here](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:e1101)) that your very problem is prone to giving a "false positive" error.

So if you get the error code 1101 (should be mentioned somewhere) but your code is working as expected, it might be okay to ignore this error. You can in this case disable Pylint for this occurrence by adding `# pylint: disable=E1101` to your code:

```
db.session.add(Error)  # pylint: disable=E1101
```